# Remote invocation of shell script

Tags: server, ssh

There are two systems **A** and **B**. I have two shell scripts on **A** (called as server).

> **B** has to call these shell scripts and only if **B** is authenticated **A** has
>   to run shell scripts and send the output to **B** (client).

Call to shell scripts will also include command line arguments.

How to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Install `openssh-server` on system **A**:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then from system **B** type:

```
ssh -t user_login@ip_of_system_A "/path_to_your_script arg1 arg2"
```

Just replace `user_login`, `ip_of_system_A` and `path_to_your_script` for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

In A you must place your user@A_ip-adress

```
   for host in A; do echo "== $host =="; ssh $host '/path_to_script_in_A/script; echo'; done
```